# Can the VPN built into Windows 7 replace the Cisco VPN client?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

Is there any way that the built-in VPN client in Windows 7 can be used to replace the Cisco VPN client?

I have tried several times using different methods and have failed. It seems that inputting IP addresses and information for the connection doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Windows has supported IPsec/L2TP VPNs for more than a decade, and PPTP hasn't been the default in years. Windows also supports SSL VPNs. All current Windows VPN protocols are fully standards-compliant. The problem likely has NOTHING to do with Windows and everything to do with the extra things that the Cisco VPN client is doing beyond just standard IKE negotiation, etc. In order to even possibly use the native client rather than the Cisco client, you'll need to know the authentication and encryption algorithms and mechanisms in use, the keying parameters, any RADIUS attributes that may be used, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Windows uses PPTP for its VPN, where Cisco uses IPSec or SSL (if you're using the AnyConnect software). So no, Windows cannot natively connect to a Cisco VPN because they use different protocols for the tunnel.

Comment: +1 This is correct. Cisco used to use IPSec, but has switched to SSL (with the AnyConnect client).

Comment: Windows allows L2TP/IPsec, SSTP, PPTP and IKEv2. It is not restricted to PPTP. (At least, Windows 7.)

Comment: Windows has supported L2tp over IPsec since at least Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 after entering your ip address, username, and password it seems like it goes into a loop of trying something over and over (for a few minutes) and then eventually gives you an error dialog for "error 800".

I usually use the included vpn client in Apple Snow Leopard which connects in seconds and is easy to setup.

Answer (score 0):

[A tutorial](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/08/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-connection-in-windows-7/) on how to set a VPN connection in windows 7.

The caveat is the Windows 7 VPN Requirements. DirectAccess I believe only works with Windows Server 2008 R2 and the Agile VPN client only supports IKEv2 gateways. [Source](http://wiki.strongswan.org/wiki/strongswan/Windows7)

Comment: Well, honestly, I kind of figured out what the tutorial told me myself.